# Playwright: how to test that an element does not have a `hidden` attribute?

Tags: playwright

I need to check whether an element on my website has the `hidden` attribute. But this element is inside a container that can be hidden itself:

```html
<div class="container"><!-- Can have `hidden` attribute, too! -->
  <ul>
    <li hidden>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This makes it impossible to use `toBeVisible()` or `not.toBeVisible()`. So I tried `not.toHaveAttribute()`.

The following does not work:

```js
await expect(listItem).not.toHaveAttribute('hidden') // Expects value argument
```

Neither does:

```js
await expect(listItem).not.toHaveAttribute('hidden', '') // Expected string: not "", Received string: ""
```

This seems wrong to me, because as there is no `hidden` attribute at all, I would not expect this to result its value in `""`.

I'm doing it in a different way now:

```js
await expect(list.locator('li:not([hidden])')).toHaveCount(1)
```

But this feels ugly to me. Any suggestions on how to make `not.toHaveAttribute()` work?

Comment: `toBeHidden` won't help?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

There is no built-in assertion for such a case. However, you can use the `getAttribute` method to get the `hidden` attribute and then verify it is not equal to the `null`.

```js
test('container and element are hidden', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.setContent(`
    <div class="container" hidden>
      <ul>
        <li hidden>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `);
  const hidden = await page.locator('li').first().getAttribute('hidden');

  expect(hidden).not.toBeNull() // ✅ Passed
});
```

```js
test('element is hidden', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.setContent(`
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li hidden>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `);
  const hidden = await page.locator('li').first().getAttribute('hidden');

  expect(hidden).not.toBeNull() // ✅ Passed
});
```

```js
test('element is not hidden', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.setContent(`
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li hidden>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `);
  // Getting attribute of element that doesn't have hidden attribute. We will receive null
  const hidden = await page.locator('li').last().getAttribute('hidden');

  expect(hidden).not.toBeNull() // ❌ Failed
});
```

Comment: The thing is that the element itself is inside another container, and this one can be hidden, too, so I think `toBeHidden()` would also be true if the container is hidden, but the list item itself has no `hidden` attribute.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim So what are you trying to verify? Can you please provide a real HTML example?

Comment: I updated my initial post with some details. 

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim updated my answer. Hope it works for you.